# Unable to Delete Reference, yellow triangle visible

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, f#

I am working on a project and there is yellow triangle on a FSharp.Core reference , so I decided to remove this reference and add again.

But when I right click on this reference, there is no option to remove the reference. I also tried to remove it through delete button but this didn't work either.

But all other references are working fine. I can delete or  add them.

I have no idea why this is happening. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Open the `fsproj` file in a text editor and remove the reference from there, then reload in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, that works.